# How to replace text between <span> tags in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've defined a `price` variable:

`price = '7.12'`

And I'm trying to replace the `0.00` in `<span class="rec-item-cost">0.00</span>` with `price`.

I've defined `soupPrice` to obtain the `0.00` from the  tags.

`soupPrice = BeautifulSoup('<span class="rec-item-cost">0.00</span>', 'lxml').span.text`

And then I tried:

`soupPrice = BeautifulSoup('<span class="rec-item-cost">0.00</span>', 'lxml').span.text.replace_with(price)`

Which yields the error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'replace_with'`

So I then tried removing the `.text` part of the code:

`soupPrice = BeautifulSoup('<span class="rec-item-cost">0.00</span>', 'lxml').span.replace_with(price)`

And this time, if I write `print(soupPrice)`, I just get:

`<span class="rec-item-cost">0.00</span>`

How should I write the code so that it properly replaces the 0.00 with 7.12?

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Changing%20attribute%20values) you can use replaceWith

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<span class="rec-item-cost">0.00</span'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
price = '7.12'
soup.select_one('.rec-item-cost').contents[0].replaceWith(price)
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
price = 7.12
soupPrice = BeautifulSoup('<span class="rec-item-cost">0.00</span>', 'lxml').span
new_price = str(soupPrice).replace(soupPrice.text,str(price))
print(new_price)
```

Output:

```
<span class="rec-item-cost">7.12</span>
```